# LibGDX ScalingViewport not changing position

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am trying to develop an Android app and I have stumbled across a really nasty problem.

I am trying to use a different viewport from my "main" one for a different stage to control certain elements. I have started using Scaling viewport with Scaling.none, as it seems the most appropriate for what I am looking for. The problem is, when I try to change its position, it simply does not move! It just stays in the center of the screen. Here is the code I am using in the contructor for the viewports:

```
viewport = new StretchViewport(720, 1280, cam);
viewport.apply();
cam.position.set(cam.viewportWidth / 2, cam.viewportHeight / 2,0);

secondaryViewport = new ScalingViewport(Scaling.none, 480, 421);
secondaryViewport.setScreenPosition(240, 0);
```

Can't Scaling viewports be moved?

EDIT: Here is my render() method:

```
@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
    cam.update();
    secondaryViewport.getCamera().update();
    sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    sb.begin();
    sb.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    sb.draw(bg, cam.position.x - cam.viewportWidth / 2, 0, cam.viewportWidth, cam.viewportHeight);
    sb.end();
    stage.getViewport().apply();
    stage.draw();
    stage.act();
    secondaryStage.getViewport().apply();
    secondaryStage.draw();
    secondaryStage.act();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution was

```
secondaryStage.getViewport().setScreenPosition(x, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default camera position of `Viewport` is at at `0,0,0`

Use this  `secondaryViewport.getCamera().position.set(100,100,0);` to change position of secondaryViewport.

```
secondaryViewport = new ScalingViewport(Scaling.none, 480, 421);
```

By this statement you're creating a new `Camera` that is different from the camera which is used in your `StretchViewport`.

Comment: how you're using another viewport ?

Comment: Would you like me to paste the code from my render() method here?

Comment: Ok, I added it!

Comment: Is your `secondaryStage` having `secondaryViewport` how you created `secondaryStage` ?

Comment: I tried using a FitViewport, too, but it still won't let me move it around

Comment: Yes, my secondaryStage has secondaryViewport assigned to it

Comment: try this `secondaryStage.getViewport().getCamera().position.set(10,10,0);`

Comment: Well, if I do that, the camera does indeed move (the actors inside the secondaryStage change position), but the viewport stays in the same position

Comment: I found the solution! It was secondaryStage.getViewport().setScreenPosition(x, y)